# Sound detection of cutting woods

Tags: audio, machine-learning, sensors

Im really new to machine Learning.I have a project to identify a given sound.(Ex: cutting wood)In the audio clip there will be several sound. What i need to do is recognise that particular sound from it. I red some articles about machine learning. But i still have lack of knowledge where to start this project and also I'm running out of time.

Any help will be really appreciated. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Can i directly perform template(algorithms) matching for a sound?

Answer (score 1):

It's a long journey ahead of you and Stack Overflow isn't a good place for asking such a generic question. Consult [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section for more.

To get you started, here are some web sites:

- [Awesome Bioacoustic](https://github.com/ybayle/awesome-bioacoustic)
- [Comparative Audio Analysis With Wavenet, MFCCs, UMAP, t-SNE and PCA](https://medium.com/@LeonFedden/comparative-audio-analysis-with-wavenet-mfccs-umap-t-sne-and-pca-cb8237bfce2f)

Here are two small repos of mine related to audio classification:

- [Gender classification from audio](https://github.com/tracek/mfmodel)
- [Kiwi / not-a-kiwi](https://github.com/tracek/ornithokrites) bird calls detector

They might give you an idea where to start your project. Check the libraries I am using - likely they will be of help to you.